# How can I clear a table in database

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I want to clear a table that is in my database using PHP codes or MySQL.
Something like "Clear History" in some websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear the table content and not the table,

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `tablename`;
```

To remove the table,

```
DROP TABLE `tablename`;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TRUNCATE` to delete the content of a table:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `table`
```

Answer (score 0):

`TRUNCATE TABLE table` is the right option for clear history or empty table as you said

Answer (score -1):

Not Delet!
Clear
in fact I want to make my table empty, that can be filled with data in future
in other websites I saw it by clicking on "Clear History"
Like last table in this address:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp